# installing cuckoo on a separated network?

Tags: automated-tests, malware, malware-detection, cuckoo

I am wanting to analyze malware using cuckoo https://cuckoo.sh/docs/introduction/index.html. I understand the installation but I want to make sure my host and guest cannot infect my network. I have a virtual machine inside the network that I plan to install virtualbox on and create a host and guest virtual machine. The thing the directions don't explain is how do I make sure these virtual boxes do not infect the outside network. Please let me know if you have any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Virtual-box takes care of it by creating a NAT with the "router" being your host PC and virtually separating the two networks from each other, making it impossible to access it from outside. So you don't have to worry about it.

Links for further reading:

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch13.html

Comment: What is the most secure options between bridged, internal and host only networking? I need to justify that I will not infect the host when I put malware on the guest.

Comment: as I said, I'd go with the defaults (NAT), I run cuckoo myself and it's the most secure you probaby can get